# Problems with update

Tags: apt

I have a problem with updates.

During update, i receive the following message.

```
Failed to download repository information
Check your Internet connection.
W:Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/ gwendal-lebihan-dev/ cinnamon-stable/ ubuntu/ dists/ precise/ main/ source/ Sources  404  Not Found
```

and also a couples of broken patheses, that are not allowed to post, according to link policy i this site

I am a newby in this, so please help.

Yeah. Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: check your internet connection.

Comment: The PPA doesn't/no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

The PPA doesn't seem to exist. It may be that the PPA existed, but the maintainer deleted it. The maintainer has nightly Cinnamon builds still available as a separate PPA.

A list of available PPAs by the maintainer are [here](https://launchpad.net/~gwendal-lebihan-dev).